# Reputation sums not adding up

Tags: support, reputation

Today, my daily total showed 61. Adding up votes, I couldn't find where the odd 1 came from. What's its likely source?

Answer (score 11):

I can't prove it, of course, but the most likely explanation is that you downvoted an answer yesterday or earlier, and it was deleted today. This gives you back the 1 reputation you paid when downvoting the answer.